# Android SQLite Query and using cursor to filter and order rows

Tags: android

Currently I am making android program which filters rows based on name using **where** query, however when I use it together with **order by** query (time), ordering doesn't work. If I just use order by without WHERE it works fine.

```
String WHERE="name LIKE'%John%';";

Cursor cur = db.query("tbl_schedule", 
            null, WHERE, null, null, null, "time");
```

Comment: `"name LIKE'%John%';"` should have no `;` since that ends the command before the order by clause: `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE x ; ORDER BY y`